# SoundCloud Javascript SDK 3.0 put methods fails

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud, put

I am currently working on a service using the SoundCloud Javascript SDK 3.0, and I have a problem with the PUT methods.

All calls respond with this HTTP error : `401 Unauthorized`

Here my JS code, similar to the [SDK documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#follow) :

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
  redirect_uri: 'http://example.com/callback'
});

SC.connect().then(function() {
  SC.put('/me/followings/3207').then(function(){
    alert('follow ok');
  });
});
```

All PUT calls pose the same problem : `me/favorites/TRACKID`, `me/followings/USERID`, `me/track_reposts/TRACKID`...

Someone would have an idea about this?

Comment: Have you registred your app?

Comment: Yes, and my other calls (stream...) work correctly

Answer (score 0):

for use follow functionality you must be authenticated. use first:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        redirect_uri: 'http://example.com/callback'
    });

    // initiate auth popup
    SC.connect().then(function() {
        return SC.get('/me');
    }).then(function(me) {
        alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
    });
</script>
```

only after you can use

```
SC.connect().then(function() {
    SC.put('/me/followings/3207').then(function(){
        alert('follow ok');
    });
});
```

Comment: you can make invisible authentication only with Ruby or Python

Comment: That's what I do. I am authenticated when I call `SC.put` but the response is always `401`

Comment: are you on local server? because not working with local server

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem on my production server

Comment: ok i have try with my soundcloud app and your parameter. It's work fine but the id 3207 doesn't work. please check with another id.  Have you configured "Redirect url" and "Website for your app" in your soundcloud app settings?

Comment: Thanks for your help! The id 3207 was just for the example. My app is correctly configured with a redirect url similar to app website url